# Is "http://www.excbadaccess.com/" is part of Stack Overflow or not?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

I found two sites which looks similar to Stack Overflow.

- http://www.dyndnscommunity.com/
- http://www.excbadaccess.com/ (hmm - that's for the iPhone, I didn't notice the crowd over there. Why is it so?)

Both sites are Q&A sites for different purposes. But I didn't notice the accounts tab in users details (association account).

I mean, are they using the API of Stack Overflow to build their own site or something else?
What should we take care before signing up to those sites? (I mean a trustful site (as Stack Overflow) or not.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These sites are Stack Exchange 1.0 sites and are separate from Stack Exchange et al.

You were able to pay for your own version before the [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) process started.

There is a list of [SE1.0 sites available here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) and both of these sites are listed.

Comment: Update - it seems the list of SE 1.0 sites is no longer available, presumably due to them being closed down...