# Is EXEC_BAD_ACCESS a StackExchange site, or a mere copy?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is “www.excbadaccess.com/” is part of Stack Overflow or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73188/is-http-www-excbadaccess-com-is-part-of-stack-overflow-or-not)

The other night I stumbled across http://www.excbadaccess.com/, and assumed it was a Stack Exchange based site, but now I'm not so sure. Is this actually a Stack Exchange site, or a poor mans knock-off? And what is the best way to tell whether a site is or isn't a Stack Exchange one?

Comment: Poor-man's knock-off? Considering that it implements every feature of SE that I can think of, it would have to be an extremely good replica if it weren't just a copy of the SE code!